# Issue with SSH connection on Mac OS 10.14.6

Tags: macos, ssh, sftp, filezilla

I'm setting up a connect to sftp remote server, but all my requests failed down by time out.
Also have tried to connect through the filezilla, but got the same output. What sort of problem I have faced and how fix that?
Thanks in advance

```
(base) macbook-air:~ username$ ssh root@***.**.***.*
ssh: connect to host ***.**.***.* port 22: Operation timed out
(base) macbook-air:~ username$ ssh root@178.208.83.17
The authenticity of host '178.208.83.17 (178.208.83.17)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2FcbPfouRMFt9G6ToDDr3WyFZq7cWNoxnc6EmauZ388.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '178.208.83.17' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password: 
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 178.208.83.17 port 22: Operation timed out
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that *ssh* and *sftp* are different protocols. An *sftp* server will typically only allow you access to transfer files, not give you shell access to execute commands like you would over ssh.

My guess is that you can not connect to the server with ssh. You can try the sftp command instead.

[Link to article about using sftp in macOS Terminal](https://beebom.com/how-to-use-mac-terminal-ftp-sftp-client/)

Comment: Thanks for your advice and article, but I have faced with the same problem (Operation timed out) after run sftp username@server_ip.